# format string before passing it to another filter

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a filter which accepts string, and i should format this string with another filter before passing it to first filter. I know that I can do it with help of "with block", but this code is around whole code base and i was looking for more neat solution. May be there is a way to control order of operations in django template language
Here what i have:

```
    # html file
    {{ params|get:'route[{}][input_address]'|format_string:0 }}

    # filters
    @register.filter
    def format_string(text, fmt):
        return text.format(fmt)

    @register.filter
    def get_list(querydict, item):
        if isinstance(querydict, QueryDict):
            return querydict.getlist(item)
        return querydict.get(item)
```

I have also tried to take that in brackets but there is syntax error

Comment: Please don't. Django's template language deliberately does not implement such logic, since such logic does *not* belong in the template, but in the view.

Comment: i cant format it in view. I have series of fields route[0][address], route[0][city], route[1][address], route[1][city], and so on. I have number of routes and I should render corresponding inputs in for loop

Comment: normally you can set attributes on your objects, or pass a list of dictionaries, etc. for example to "prepare" the data in a format that makes it easy for the template. Such logic belongs in the view, not in the template.

Comment: you mean array of routes like routes 
`[{'address': ... , city: ..., ..}, ... ]`
How would an html form post nested dictionary. because i have this route inputs and should validate them, and return back to template if validation is not succeded.
` <input type="text"
             name="route[0][input_address]"
             {% if params|get:'route[0][input_address]' %}
             value="{{params|get:'route[0][input_address]'}}"
             {% endif %}>`